# in sql the following query is given my desired output but in laravel model how can I retrieve it?

Tags: laravel

sql query is

```
select *,sum(diposit_amount) as total from `diposits` group by `member_id`;
```

I am trying in model like this way

```
App\diposit::groupBy('member_id')
->selectRaw('*,sum(diposit_amount) as total')
->get();
```

but it gives errors "SQLSTATE[42000]: Syntax error or access violation: 1055 'pos.diposits.id' isn't in GROUP BY (SQL: select *,sum(diposit_amount) as total from `diposits` group by `member_id`) (View: C:\xampp\htdocs\pos\resources\views\welcome.blade.php) "

Comment: In your file `config/connections.php` there's a setting for `strict`, which is likely set to `true` right now. If you change that to `false`, it _should_ work. Not sure on the implications of doing that, if any.

Comment: @TimLewis should be `config/database.php` as far as i know

Comment: @simonecosci Woops, that's correct, `connections` is the array in `config/database.php`; good catch.

Comment: Thanks @TimLewis its working now